# External class object not holding data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a class UserData which I imported to this viewcontroller but the data on the cell
is blank.
again userdata is an object of UserData, another class. I did `#import "UserData.h"` but the table is empty
 if I put @"something" in replacement of detailsstring or titlestring, it shows up on the table

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
detailsstring = userdata.details;
titlestring = userdata.title;

tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:detailsstring, nil];
 tablesubtitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:titlestring, nil];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

and...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tablesubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
```

Comment: Did you check, if userdata.title contains an instance of `NSString` in the beginning? (`NSLog(@"%@, %@", userdata.details, userdata.title);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to share data between view controllers, when you use `#import "yourClass"` you create an new instanse of that clas with the same name, but will not hold the same content(the new one will be nil). For sharing data between views you can use delegates like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183611/passing-object-between-view-controllers-in-objective-c), Core data or **SQLite** can bee used for the same purpose. But delegete is better as i have seen from all the answer&comments out there:)

**EDIT** As **[Jack Lawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428908/jack-lawrence)** too has commented, NSUserDeffaults is not a proper way for sharing data between classes&objects. Just because of its easy-usability I mentioned defaults. I hope this edit will be useful for ones who see this answer later

Comment: jees, that's it! Makes perfect sense, I really didn't know how to do this. But how do I choose a delegate???

Comment: Take a look at this please: http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/08/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-objective-c.html .. I haven't figure out delegating enoughly yyet so i dont want to mix your mind:) I hope this link will hwlp. If not, i can share code for NSUserDeffaults, which not wanted for such a job:)

Comment: Apple strongly recommends against storing non-settings-related data in `NSUserDefaults` because of performance issues. Moreover, `NSUserDefaults`, as its name implies, is for defaults (settings) not for storing arbitrary data. I would recommend using synthesized properties, property lists (plists), SQLite, or Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

if you are replacing `detailsstring` with a string literal and everything works, then `detailsstring` must be nil in `viewDidLoad`